# PHP - capturing multiple variables from each row of a dynamic list with dropdowns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of plants that is a result of a mysql search. The list will have an undefined number of plants in it. There is a different plant in each row of this list, and 2 select dropdowns, one for choosing the number of plants, and one for choosing the size of the plant.

Each row of this plant list therefore has 4 variables that I would like to capture and update the database table with when the submit button is clicked: the plant ID, the plant name, the count, and the size.

I have greatly simplified the code below, as this actually represents about 200 lines of code. So I included only what was necessary to convey my problem.

The code below works well enough to give me only the values for the last row of the list. I realize that I am dealing with an array of arrays here. I have tried many many solutions for several hours, and now just need to ask for help with this. Thank you in advance for your gracious help. I'm still quite new at this.

```
... mysql query that creates this plant list result

if($r) {

echo '<form action="plantlist.php" method="POST">';

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))) {

     echo '<table>
              <tr>
                 <td>' . $plant_id . '</td>
                 <td>' . $plant_name . '</td>
                 <td>
                    <select name="count" value="' . $count . '"> 
                       <option value="1">1</option>
                       <option value="2">2</option>
                       <option value="3">3</option>
                       <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                    <select name="size" value="' . $size .'">  
                       <option value="1">1 foot</option>
                       <option value="2">2 feet</option>
                       <option value="3">3 feet</option>
                       <option value="4">4 feet</option>
                    </select>
                 </td>
              </tr>
           </table>';

}
 echo '<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="" />
       </form>';

$row_results = array($plant_id, $plant_name, $count, $size);

}  // end while loop

$whole_list_results = array($row_results);

       foreach($whole_list_results as $result) {

            $q = "UPDATE drip_zones SET count = '$count', 
                  size = '$size' WHERE plant_id = '$plant_id' 
                  AND plant_name = '$plant_name'";

            $r = @mysqli_query ($db, $q); // run query
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the last line you are overwriting the $row_results variable which is why you are always getting the last row.

Change to:

```
 $row_results = array();
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))) {
```

And:

```
  echo '<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="" />
   </form>';

  $row_results[] = array('plant_id' => $plant_id, 
                         'plant_name' => $plant_name, 
                         'count' => $count, 
                         'size' => $size);
```

Finally you can loop though these results by changing:

```
   foreach($row_results as $result) {

        $q = "UPDATE drip_zones SET count = '". $result['count'] ."', 
              size = '". $result['size']. "' WHERE plant_id = '" .$result['plant_id'] ."' 
              AND plant_name = '" .$result['plant_name'] ."'";

        $r = @mysqli_query ($db, $q); // run query
   }
```

However you seem to have select boxes which wont do anything in this script snippet. I presume that is handled elsewhere in the script. In fact in its current state this would just store what it already has so actually what you are asking doesnt make any sense...

Comment: Thank you, @user3238482. I like that you included the revision on the UPDATE code. I'll give this a try.

Comment: Also as PBorek pointed out - the $row_results[] = array(.. bit. needs to be moved inside of the while loop

Comment: Thank you, @user3238482. I marked this the correct answer. All answers worked for me. But yours went further with helping with the mysql update code. That was very helpful. I'm rocking now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it seems that

```
$row_results = array($plant_id, $plant_name, $count, $size);
```

is outside while (it is in if block).

Second, you should change it to:

```
$row_results[] = array($plant_id, $plant_name, $count, $size);
```

And probably define it before if:

```
$row_results = array();
```

Then, you can just use:

```
foreach($row_results as $result) {
  echo $result[0];
  echo $result[1];
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$whole_list_results = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))) {

    // ...

    $row_results = array($plant_id, $plant_name, $count, $size);
    $whole_list_results[] = $row_results;
}  // end while loop
```